# Loader in angular2 Http request

Tags: angular

I want to show a loader when a http request

```
return this.http.get(this._apiUrl)
            //.map(res =><Location[]> res.json())
            .map(res => res.json())
            .filter(x => x.length > 0)
            .delay(5000)
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

in above code where I can specify a loader template ?

Comment: try https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 1):

You must have read our conversation. If not, read it first. then you may try this solution.

You are going to return an `observer`. 
And I consider here that may be your `fetch function` is written in some `external service`.

```
fetch(){ 
return this.http.get(this._apiUrl) //.map(res => res.json()) .map(res => res.json()) .filter(x => x.length > 0) .delay(5000) .catch(this.handleError); 
}
```

So, I'd suggest to add it before you subscribe to an returned observer like this,

```
this.isLoading=true;
this.externalService.fetch.subscribe((result) =>{ 
                    this.result =result
                    },
                    (err)=>console.log(err),
                    ()=>{console.log("Done")
                          this.isLoading=false;
                    });
```

}

check this for reference http://plnkr.co/edit/UMMFk57seNrxqdgyeQIT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

`Http` itself doesn't provide any direct support for showing loaders.

Just set a field in your component or a service

```
fetchData() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  return this.http.get(this._apiUrl)
        //.map(res =><Location[]> res.json())
        .map(res => res.json())
        .filter(x => x.length > 0)
        .delay(5000)
        .catch(this.handleError)
        .do(this.isLoading = false);
}
```

Then bind the visibility of the loader to `isLoading`

```
<my-loader *ngIf="isLoading"></my-loader>
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `before` when you actually subscribe to an observer?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I haven't encountered this operator yet. Do you have a link I couldn't find anything about it?

Comment: No I'm not talking about an operator. I'm talking about the place. When you subscribe to an observer you can use it before subscription or before when you call the service.

Comment: I see. Right. I don't use TS and Rx myself. Do you think it work to add a `do(_ => this.isLoading = true)` before `http.get()`. Like `new Observable.of([1]).do(_ => this.isLoading = true).map(_ => this.http.get(...))...`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UMMFk57seNrxqdgyeQIT?p=preview check this one by clicking friends tab.

Comment: One doesn't always want to subscribe immediately where the observable is created. You might want to pass the observable around and then subscribe elsewhere because this way you get returned a subscription which isn't always helpful. You might chain other operators to the observable returned by `fetchData()` (to use the name from my answer) which you can only with an observable but not with a subscription.

Comment: I agree with your explanation. But then consider a scenario: if  `fetch` fun is written in `externalService` then how would you be able to access '<my-loader *ngIf="isLoading"></my-loader>' from `externalService`?

Comment: The service would need to provide some hook. For example provide an observable where you can subscribe to `myFetchService.isLoadingChange.subscribe(value => this.isLoading = value);`   and implement what we discussed above to emit `true`/`false` when a new request is made/completed.

Comment: Yes so again my first suggestion comes into pic that it is good to use it before subscribing to returned observer.

Comment: I would say - it depends. The question doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Yes true and agreed.Thanks !